# Scroll to top of the page on pagination pagechange w/o router interactions

Tags: scroll, pagination, angular7, angular-universal

I am working on an application where we list some data, with ngb-pagination and don't use routing for the change, so we can't use scrollPositionRestoration which is router related.
My issue is that I'd like to move the current view(since pagination is on the bottom of the page) to be resetted to the top. I can't access the dom directly b/c of universal. So window.scrollTo is out.

What is a good and elegant way to achieve the goal i'd like?

router-scroll is out since no real routing happens
direct dom access is forbidden

The snipped would not make any difference to the issue. I just want to extend my existing current function that's called when pagination page-change happens.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if code is executed on the client and call window.scrollTo only in that case. Not much elegance though.

```
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platform,
) {}

goToTop() {
  it (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
    window.scrollTo(...);
  }
}
```